# How to compare the year with the current year in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, date

I am new to iPhone development. I am parsing a XML URL and display the title, date and summary in a table view.

I noticed some of the date were very old like "Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 -0500", so I don't want to display the dates which are 1 year older than the current year. How to do that? I used the sample code from [this](http://theappleblog.com/2008/08/04/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/) site for parsing and display the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dealing with Dates (NSDate Class) is a rather painfull thing to do, and it caused me a lot of trouble and anger.

basically you have different approaches:

1.) get components from your date and compare them to your reference dates..
that could look something like this:

//given that you have an NSDate object called dateOfSearch

```
unsigned int unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *comp; 


NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];


comp = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:dateOfSearch];
NSInteger *year = [comp year];
```

//year no contains the year that is being contained by the dateOfSearch object.
//mind you: this is a basic example to show you how to extract the year of an NSDate Object

2.) use NSDate's `timeReferenceSince1970` or other "equivalents" to do comparison (easier)

NSDate's timeReference Methods return the amount of seconds between two referenceDates

so a good approach would be

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init] //today
NSDate *pastDate = [self getPastDateFromWhereEver];
NSTimeInterval *difference =  [pastDate timeIntervalSinceDate:today];
```

if(difference < .....)

hope that helps

cheers

Answer (score 2):

in addition to samsam's answer and after looking into your sample-code, you have to convert your date-string to a NSDate object:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 -0500"];
```

Comment: speaking about NSDateFormatters... they're probably the most ressource-munching elements in the world :)... especially when parsing a lot of Elements, watch out that you only create (read: alloc, init) once.. just in case you're wondering what eats up your performance.